# The number 3750 satisfies ϕ(3750)=1000 ϕ(3750)=1000. Find a number a that has the following three properties

Tags: number-theory

I've seen this problem posted here before, but I'm still a bit confused on how to answer this problem.

The number 3750 satisfies $ ϕ(3750)=1000$. Find a number a that has the following three properties:

$a≡7^{3003}\mod3750$

$1≤a≤5000$

a is not divisible by 7

I know we're supposed to use Euler's function, so we know that:

$a^{1000} ≡ 1\mod3750$

But what can we draw from that fact specifically? Because it tells us about the congruency to 1, not 7^3003.

Any hints appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: By $\Phi$ do you mean the [totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)?  It is usually written $\phi$ and I would make that explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $7$ is coprime to $3750$, what can you say about $7^{1000}$?  What does that tell you about $7^{3003}?$